# Are heuristic portfolios efficient portfolios?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, asset-allocation

Markowitz's definition of an efficient portfolio is one that minimizes portfolio risk for a given level of expected return. He therefore calls portfolios along the efficient frontier "frontier portfolios" as well as "efficient portfolios".

There also exist well-performing strategies called heuristic portfolios including the **equally-weighted (1/N) portfolio,** and **inverse-volatility portfolio (IVP)**. I know the 1/N portfolio doesn't lie on the efficient frontier, but is known to often outperform all frontier (efficient) portfolios out-of-sample. There's also no comment about the IVP being efficient. Can we call these two heuristic portfolios efficient portfolios?

optional question: Are the following strategies also efficient portfolios or no?

- hierarchical risk parity portfolio (HRP)
- maximum diversification portfolio (MDP)
- maximum decorrelation portfolio

Comment: Some of these are efficient under special assumptions, for ex. Minimum Variance (which you did not mention) is efficient if expected returns are the same, 1/N is efficient if in addition the covariance matrix is the identity, MDP is efficient if excess returns on assets are proportional to their volatility, etc. I don't have a complete listing of the required conditions, but it would be interesting.

Comment: the min variance portfolio is one of Markowitz' efficient portfolios that lie on the frontier so i knew already it was efficient. but you did answer the question on heuristic portfolios: to confirm, are you saying that if the 1/N (or MDP) is made efficient by having an identity covariance matrix (or having asset excess returns that are proportional to their volatility, in the case of MDP), then it is efficient *because* the said condition minimizes *that* portfolio's risk? (in other words, Markowitz's definition of efficiency = low risk, is upheld even for the heuristics)